# Is it possible to improve the research dpt results?

Tags: theme-hospital

Is there a point to build more than one research dpt?
Or to put more than one doctor at work in the research dpt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More doctors - **yes**! Each active researcher in the Research Department (i.e. a doctor who is able to sit at a free desk and get in and out of the room) will reduce the amount of time required for developments to be researched.

Additional research *departments*, however, are unlikely to provide a notable benefit. The only thing you'll get from two research departments would be two Auto-Autopsy machines, and there's unlikely to be a need for this; patients can queue outside your research department for their autopsy.

You should aim to build a single research department that is as large as reasonably possible - accommodating at least 2 desks, and anywhere up to 4-6 desks on later levels.